# How to make a floating sidebar continue floating while ajax content is being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sidebar, sticky

I'm a real noob in js so the question is like the following.

I've got floating sidebar which stops floating when it reaches the footer. The js code is as follows:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function() {
        var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
        var footTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));

        var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight();

        $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (y > top) {
                if (y < maxY) {
                    $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed').removeAttr('style');
                } else {
                    $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: (maxY - top) + 'px'
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
```

This worked pretty good until I implemented ajax pagination and content loading.
The sidebar scrolls only when I view the 1st page, when the 2nd page is loaded via ajax the sidebar doesn't scroll. you can see it [here](http://www.rayshaft.com).

Do you have any ideas what i need to change in the code to make it work as I want to?

Comment: call the scroll function again after ajax success

Comment: how to do this? I don't know js

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just that you initializise `maxY` and `footTop` only once. They would need to change when you extend the document. You might recalculate them each time a scroll happens.

Comment: can you explain in details how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This one might help you with what you are looking for.

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/followalong/